# Couldn't avoid duplicates and merge rows on my views

Tags: views

I have a view of list of contents referenced in many others content types in my site.
Lets talk about just 2 content types :
A content type called *container* is referenced in a content type *position*, so we say that the container has many positions.
*Container position* is a select list field in Position, for every item in this select list, there are some fields to fill.for example if I select 'on board' I have to fill the field 'date of loading', If I select 'in the shipper' I have to fill the field 'name of shipper'.
So in my view I want to display  the list of containers with informations from the positions where they were: container;date of loading;port of loading; shipper.
When I created the view I get duplicated results for every container. I tried aggregation and distinct option, It not works, or it removes duplicates without merging the rows if use them both.
[image]
[image]

**Update:**
My question is similar to this [Views - adding relationship adds duplicate row for each relation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111013/views-adding-relationship-adds-duplicate-row-for-each-relation?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Comment: I try it and I get the same result, If I choose filter repeats it just removes rows without merging content in one row, If I choose aggregate repeates it doesn't change anything.